# How to make datediff as variable in php

Tags: php, mysql

How i can use diff as variable?

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateInterval could not be
>   converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\KP\homeSekprodi.php on line 79

```
    $hasil        = mysql_fetch_array($sqltime);
    $tglPengajuan = $hasil['tanggal'];
    $now          = date("Y-m-d");
    $now          = date_create($now);
    $tglPengajuan = date_create($tglPengajuan);
    $diff         = date_diff($tglPengajuan, $now);
    echo $diff->format("%R%a Days");
    $uptime       = mysql_query("UPDATE mahasiswa SET WaktuSekpro = '$diff'");
```

Comment: you can't insert that object, save the echoed formatted date string then use that in the insertion

Comment: FYI, and that would update all rows, if you want the update on that particular row only, feed the id as well in your WHERE clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just include in query

```
$uptime = mysql_query("UPDATE mahasiswa SET WaktuSekpro = '".$diff->format("%R%a Days")."'");
```

Answer (score 2):

Like most other variables, you need to [**assign**](https://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php) it:

```
// ...code
$diff = $diff->format("%R%a Days");
$uptime = mysql_query("UPDATE mahasiswa SET WaktuSekpro = '$diff'");
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the formatted date difference in the $diff variable, you can change this line:

```
$diff = date_diff($tglPengajuan, $now);
```

into:

```
$diff = date_diff($tglPengajuan, $now)->format("%R%a Days");
```